# How to make a 3 position switch return to the center position when keypress is released?

Tags: game-engine

I have a 3 position switch with one keypress moving the switch up, and another keypress moving the switch down. The switch needs to return to the center position when the keypress is released. How can this be accomplished with logic bricks in Blender 2.79?

Answer (score 1):

Play the "switching" animations with the action actuator in **Flipper Mode**.

The animation will be played forward when the actuator is activated (e.g. when pressing and holding the keyboard button). When reaching the end frame the last pose will remain.

When the actuator gets deactivated (e.g. via releasing the keyboard button) the animation will be player revers till the start frame.

---

*Be aware this does not deal with the situation when you press the second button while the first one is still pressed.*

---

Comment: So, for a three position switch, with the center position being the neutral, I would then need 2 animations, correct? One for the switch UP and one for the switch DOWN?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching through the Blender manual and saw 'State Controllers.' The explanation wasn't satisfying, so I looked for videos. Here are 2 excellent explanations on state controllers, that, with a small amount of imagination, can answer this question quite easily, without using animation:

[BGE 6 states](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57EEu2omTvY&t=12s)

[Blender Game Engine Basics Tutorial #6 : States & Movement #b3d #gamelogic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sASXktj3Dz0)

The first state is to enable your choice of switch position and change state. The second state makes a move to the position. The 3rd state returns to the center position and back to state 1. Follow the same steps for the other positions of the switch. The delay in the 3rd state allows the switch to remain in the selected direction until whatever it operates is finished, so adjust this as necessary.

[image: 1st State is to enable your choice]
[image: 2nd State makes a move to position]
[image: 3rd State for delay and return to center position]

Be sure to turn on debug to follow the state progression.

(Thanks, David!)